# Firebase: server side logic and real time database limitations

Tags: firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database, parse-platform

**Server side custom operations equivalent to Parse cloud code:**

Parse has the possibility to write [cloud code](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide). From my understanding of it Firebase doesn't offer any tools to do so on the console.

The only way to do so would be to implement a web-service using the Firebase API and monitor nodes changes and implement the cloud code on my own server.

- *A - Is this correct?*

**Server side rules:**

The [legacy documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-types) of Firebase describes rules which seem to be limited to deciding which user can read/write as well as validation.

```
{   
"rules": {
    "foo": {
      // /foo/ is readable by the world
      ".read": true,
      // /foo/ is writable by the world
      ".write": true,
      // data written to /foo/ must be a string less than 100 characters
      ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
    }  
 } }
```

On Parse the complexity of the rules is greater. The programmer is able to create functions to perform custom operations.

**Understanding the reason why Firebase is designed as it is:**

I imagine that the reason for not having this complexity on Firebase is that probably a node based database is more complex than a table based one and it would be better if the developer has full control of this using the web-api and a custom server app.

- *B - Is this correct?*

**Real time database limitations:**

The main limitation when using a real time database like Firebase seems to me  that once you fetch some real time data if the data contains a two way redundancy the events triggered on one node are not propagated to the node containing the redundant information.

E.g. If a user node has keys id (ids of a different node at the same level of the user node) and if I display the list of keys that a user has on a table view in order to detect if the key list has changed I need to listen to changes in the keys node (and not only to changes in the user node).

*- C: Is this correct?*

Comment: A) Yes, Maybe. Yes, there is no server side logic (code-wise). Maybe, it depends on what you are trying to do. More info is needed to provide direction. B) Firebase rules are very flexible; Rules can limit who can access data, read/write access, what kind of data, type of data, location of data etc. C) No. You can observe any node for changes. In your example, you should probably have the keys node as a separate node than the user node and have users observe the /keys/ node.

Comment: Hello Jay, thanks for the reply. Regarding A) I added some details. Regarding C) it feels to me that this relies on the programmer observing changes in order to create a proper UX, is this correct? For example as programmer I need to observe values and all dependencies in order to capture differences (this is due to data redundancy).

Comment: A) There is no code on the Firebase server. Can you provide a use case? C) Data doesn't necessarily need to be redundant, but it can be. You only need to observe changes for the specific data you are interested in. Suppose you have a /users node and /favorite_food node of each user. If your UI is displaying a list of users and one of them changes their favorite food, you don't really care - you are just interested in the list of users. So you would observe the /users node and not the /favorite_food node. Do you have a use case as that would make it easier to address.

Comment: Wow.... nice conversation. Sounds like you have a great answer to all three questions here Jay!

Answer (score 2):

The question is a tad vague as there are no use cases but based on the comments, here you go.

A) Yes, Maybe.
Yes, there is no server side logic (code-wise).
Maybe, it depends on what you are trying to do.

B) Firebase rules are very flexible; Rules can limit who can access data, read/write access, what kind of data, type of data, location of data etc. It is neither more or less complex than a 'table based one'. It's just a different way to verify, validate and store your data.

Just an FYI: Parse was was backed by MongoDB which is a document based NoSQL database (it's not table-based). On the back-end, Parse data was stored in a way similar to Firebase. (it's actually BSON). Their front-end implementation were objects that wrapped around JSON structures which gave the feeling that it was more table-like than Firebase, and that lead to the direct ability to have relationships between PFobjects.

C) No. You can observe any node for changes. In your example, you should probably have the keys node as a separate node than the /user node and have users observe the /keys node.

To expand on that a bit, data doesn't necessarily need to be redundant, but it can be. You only need to observe changes for the specific data you are interested in.

Suppose you have a /users node and /favorite_food node of each user. If your UI is displaying a list of users and one of them changes their favorite food, you don't really care - you are just interested in the list of users. So you would observe the /users node and not the /favorite_food node.

Comment: I am trying to understand the differences between the two databases. So no specific use case in mind. I could make one up (e.g. when a value is changed use cloud code to update a different node/table with a short summary of the value changes).

Comment: @mm24 Yeah, I understand totally. I started with Parse several years ago and it took me a while to wrap my brain around Firebase. In your comment example, you won't need cloud code as when a client changes a value in a node, the other clients that are observing that node will automatically receive an event of that change with the newly updated data. So the essence of that statement is that Firebase handles the event for you - however, you need to put the data there to start with.

Comment: @mm24 As a followup thought, this issue becomes challenging in Firebase when automating a task; say at 2am each morning delete all posts from the prior day. That would have to be done server side - on the flip side, If the data is just sitting there, who cares! It doesn't really matter when it gets deleted so any client app could just do that whenever it connects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments. I'll read this properly tomorrow and do some additional research to better understand it. Then willl accept. Thanks :)